# SVN Cannot find Hooks Folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using tfs2svn to migrate our Team Foundation Server to svn.  I am running into the following issue:

[image]

From researching online, it seems I need to create a batch file named 'pre-revprop-change' containing and exit code of 0 and put it in my local repositories 'hooks' folder.  However, I do not see a hooks folder in the repo or inside the .svn folder.  Should I be seeing the hooks folder if I'm browsing through Windows Explorer?  I cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repo != Working Copy. If it has a `.svn` folder it's a working copy. You need to open the **repository** in Windows explorer (not in TortoiseSVN Repo-browser). It should look like this:

- conf
- db
- format
- hooks
- locks
- README.txt
- svn.ico

**Edit:** I've never used tfs2svn but I've found the [screen-shots](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tfs2svn/) in the tfs2svn project page and the program features a very prominent "SVN destination settings" section with a "SVN repository" field. While it's a URL, it should be a fairly good hint of where the repo is.

Comment: I'm still very green with SVN...how exactly would I find my local repo on my machine?  Is it something I would have to explicitly create, or is it created when you do a Checkout?

Comment: It's something you need to create. You cannot anything with Subversion (checkout, update, commit...) unless to have a repository to do it against. I suspect that `tfs2svn` did it for you; didn't it ask for a folder or something?